# applying task in k8s pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to run `kubectl -f pod.yaml` but getting this error. Any hint?

```
error: error validating "/pod.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Pod): unknown field "imagePullSecrets" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Pod, ValidationError(Pod): unknown field "nodeSelector" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Pod, ValidationError(Pod): unknown field "tasks" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Pod]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

pod.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gpu-pod-10.0.1
  namespace: e6a5089f-8e9e-4647-abe3-b8d775079565
spec:
  containers:
  - name: main
    image: bded587f4604
  imagePullSecrets: ["testo", "awsecr-cred"]
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: 11-4730
tasks:
- name: traind
  command: et estimate -e v/lat/exent_sps/enet/default_sql.spec.txt -r /out
  completions: 1
  inputs:
    datasets:
    - name: poa
      version: 2018-
      mountPath: /in/0
```

Comment: how do u do this formatting? i want to learn.

Answer (score 2):

You have an indentation error on your `pod.yaml` definition with `imagePullSecrets` and you need to specify the `- name:` for your `imagePullSecrets`. Should be something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gpu-test-test-pod-10.0.1.11-e8b74730
  namespace: test-e6a5089f-8e9e-4647-abe3-b8d775079565
spec:
  containers:
  - name: main
    image: test.io/tets/maglev-test-bded587f4604
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: testawsecr-cred
...
```

Note that `imagePullSecrets:` is plural and an [array](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#podspec-v1-core) so you can specify multiple credentials to multiple registries.

If you are using Docker you can also specify multiple credentials in `~/.docker/config.json`.

If you have the same credentials in `imagePullSecrets:` and configs in `~/.docker/config.json`, the credentials are merged.

Comment: i see. and how can i use multiple secrets?
like 
imagePullSecrets:
  - name: testawsecr-cred1
  - name: testawsecr-cred2

Comment: so like this:?  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: [testawsecr-cred1,  cred2, cred3]

Comment: i updated my pod.yaml above. and still getting:
error validating data: [ValidationError(Pod.spec.imagePullSecrets[0]): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference: got "string", expected "map", ValidationError(Pod.spec.imagePullSecrets[1]): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference: got "string", expected "map", ValidationError(Pod): unknown field "tasks" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Pod]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Comment: `- name: testawsecr-cred1`  and newline `- name: cred2`